# JavaScript/jQuery Select multiple items according to a common attribute and pass them as a String separated by a delimiter to the JavaBean

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck with this problem, since my knowledge of JavaScript and jQuery is limited. I am using JSF 2.0 and PrimeFaces 3.5. I have an ordered list of items in PrimeFaces and I want to get the selected items in order to removed them when I click the remove button. When an item in the list is selected its state changes to "ui-state-highlight". This can be seen when the browser is in debug mode and items in the list are selected. By holding down 'Ctrl' multiple items can be selected. However, in the way it is currently implemented only the index of one item is sent to my JavaBean in the back end and consequently only one item is removed from the list even if more than one are selected.

How can the JavaScript part be changed to send as a String either all the selected items separated by a delimiter like ',' or all the indices of the selected items again separated by a delimiter to my JavaBean in the back end?

JavaScript part:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on('click', '.delete_answer_button', function() {
    var selectedItem = $(this).closest('.orderlist_wrapper').find('.ui-orderlist-item.ui-state-highlight');
    if (selectedItem.length > 0) {
        deleteAnswer1([
            {name: 'index', value: selectedItem.closest('ul').find('li').index(selectedItem)}
        ]);
    }
 });
});
  </script>
```

JSF/PrimeFaces part:

```
<h:form id="form">
  <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="form_field_wrapper orderlist_wrapper">
                <p:orderList id="a123" value="#{testBean.newQuestion.answers}" var="answer" itemValue="#{answer}" converter="testConvert" controlsLocation="left">
                    <f:facet name="caption">Answers</f:facet>

                    <p:column>
                        #{answer.text}
                    </p:column>
                </p:orderList>
              <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="form_field" style="width: 40px;">
                    <p:commandButton value="" icon="ui-icon-minusthick" type="button" styleClass="icon_button delete_answer_button" />
                    <p:remoteCommand name="deleteAnswer1" actionListener="#{testBean.deleteAnswer}" update=":form:result :form:a123" />
                </h:panelGroup>

    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:outputText id="result" value="#{testBean.result}"/>

</h:form>
```

The deleteAnswer method from the JavaBean:

```
public void deleteAnswer(ActionEvent event) {
    int index = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("index"));

    List<Answer> temp = getNewQuestion().getAnswers();
    Answer temp2 = temp.get(index);
    result = "deleted " + getNewQuestion().getAnswers().get(index).toString();
    getNewQuestion().getAnswers().remove(index);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.delete_answer_button', function() {
       $(this).closest('.orderlist_wrapper').find('.ui-orderlist-item.ui-state-highlight').each(function()    {
            deleteAnswer1([
                {name: 'index', value: $(this).closest('ul').find('li').index($(this))} 
        ]);
    });
 });
});
```

You want to use the "each" iterator to loop through your items and then call the delete answer functionality for each of them.  Otherwise, you can loop through them while building up an array (or whatever container you need) - and then after the loop, call your deleteAnswer function just 
once and pass it the array.

I'm unsure about the deleteanswer syntax, but you can put a few alerts inside the each loop to determine what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Stan. But calling the deleteAnswer method every time is not producing the result I want. As the item with the given index is removed from the list the indices change. I have posted the deleteAnser methood of my JavaBean so you can see what I mean. How can I append all the indices of the selected items to a String, each separated by a comma and then call the deleteAnswer method only once and pass it that String?

Comment: I just figured out how to do it. Thanks for your help Stan.

Comment: Glad to help, I assume you used the each loop to build an array of indices or a delimited string - and then call the deleteanswer function once after the loop?

Comment: Yes I used the each loop to build a delimited String that contains all the indices I want to be removed.Then I call the deleteAnswer function once. This work fine but there might be something wrong in my code within the deleteAnswer function because when I try to delete three or more items (but not all of the items) it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. This deleteAnswer method calls in turn the deleteMeasurement function iteratively, passing every time one of the indices as a parameter. The deleteMeasurement function works correctly for a given index passed at a time. Here is my code:

Comment: Code from the deleteAnswer function:                         for(int i=0;i<indexArray.length;i++){
  indexArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(indexStringArray[i]); 
 }
 
  if(indexArray.length>1){
     removeMeasurement(indexArray[0]);
     for(int i=1;i<indexArray.length;i++){
      indexArray[i]-=1;
      removeMeasurement(indexArray[i]);
     }
    }
    else removeMeasurement(indexArray[0]);

Comment: Change your for loop to:
for (int i=indexArray.length-1;i>=0;i--)

You're removing items from the array, which changes the indices - that's why you're getting an out of bounds exception.  This shouls solve it.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after a while. Thanks a lot for your help Stan!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it append the indices to a String based on Stan's loop. Thanks for you help Stan.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.delete_answer_button', function() {
      var indexString='';
         $(this).closest('.orderlist_wrapper').find('.ui-orderlist-item.ui-state-highlight').each(function()    {
        indexString+= $(this).closest('ul').find('li').index($(this)) + ',';
      });
         deleteAnswer1([
                        {name: 'index', value: indexString} 
                ]);
   });
```

Comment: No problem - just remember to trim the "," off the end of your string before sending it to your deleteAnswer1 function:

string.substring(0, string.length-1)

Comment: I do that in Java in my deleteAnswer method, since it's much easier for me to write it in Java rather than in JavaScript.